# Deleting repetitive occurrences of same element in list

Tags: gcc, data-structures, linked-list

```
struct node * del(struct node * temp1,int num)
{
         struct node *temp2;
         temp2=NULL;

         if(temp1==NULL)
         {
                  return NULL;
         }

         if(temp1->data==num)
         {
                  temp2=temp1->next;
                  free(temp1);
                  return temp2;
         }
         else
           {
                  temp1->next=del(temp1->next,num);
           }

           return temp1;
}
```

I refer above code to delete an element from list but it can't delete all repeated values. Please correct above code or give any simple one. List is singly linear 
expecting

```
input list = 11 22 11 33 11 44 

output - after deletion of 11 list = 22 33 44

void del()
{
         int i,d;
     struct node *list,*temp;
         printf("Enter data to delete\t");
         scanf("%d",&d);
         list=start;
         for(i=1;i<n;i++)
         {
                  if(start->data==d)
                  {
                     temp=start;
                     start=start->next;
                     list=start;
                     free(temp);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                           if(list->next->data==d)
                           {
                             if(list->next->next==NULL)
                             {
                                 temp=list->next;
                                 list->next=NULL;
                                 free(temp);
                                 break;
                             }
                             temp=list->next;
                             list->next=temp->next;
                             list=list->next;
                             free(temp);
                             continue;
                           }

                           list=list->next;
                  }
         }
}
```

I follow this code also but it not works properly on gcc compiler.where n is total number of nodes.

Comment: a simple solution is to keep calling the delete function until it doesn't find the key.

Comment: @arunmoezhi- Sir,I am trying that but couldn't get success in it. Please give a code.

Comment: Why do you have a recursive code. Try to avoid recursion as much as possible. And in this case it is easy to write a iterative code for list walk

Comment: @arunmoezhi - I wrote a code using for loop ,that code works correctly on TC but it couldn't work on GCC, so I am trying other alternatives like recursion.

Comment: Then post the solution which you tried with GCC

Comment: @arunmoezhi- Sir, I update that code in question.

Comment: Why do you use a for loop. Why not a while loop till you reach the end of list.

Comment: @arunmoezhi - I used while loop with list!=NULL but it couldn't work either on GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void delall(int del)
{
                  struct node *t1,*temp;
                  t1=NULL;
                  temp=start;
                  while(temp!=NULL&&temp->data==del)
                  {
                           t1=temp;
                           temp=temp->next;
                           start=temp;
                           free(t1);
                  }
                  while(temp!=NULL)
                  {
                           if(temp->data==del)
                           {
                                    t1->next=temp->next;
                                    free(temp);
                                    temp=t1->next;

                           }
                           else
                           {
                                    t1=temp;
                                    temp=temp->next;
                           }
                  }
}
```

Comment: @arunmoezhi- I think it is more simple logic.I couldn't get it at first time.

Comment: you are essentially trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. Use `insertAtEnd()` to insert duplicate elements and `removeAll()` to remove all the occurrences of a key.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<limits.h>

struct node
{
    unsigned long key;
    struct node* next;
};

struct seekRecord
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* curr;
};

struct node* R;
struct seekRecord* seekRecord;

struct node* createNode(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* newNode = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->key = key;
    newNode->next = NULL;
}

void createSentinelNode()
{
    R = createNode(ULONG_MAX);
}

void seek(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* curr;
    struct node* next;
    prev = NULL;
    curr = R;
    next = R->next;
    while(next != NULL && curr->key != key)
    {
        prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = next->next;
    }
    seekRecord->prev = prev;
    seekRecord->curr = curr;
    return;
}

bool search(unsigned long key)
{
    seek(key);
    return seekRecord->curr->key == key;
}

bool insert(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* curr;
    seek(key);
    curr = seekRecord->curr;
    if(curr->key == key)
    {
        return false;
    }
    curr->next = createNode(key);
    return true;
}

bool remove(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* curr;
    seek(key);
    curr = seekRecord->curr;
    prev = seekRecord->prev;
    if(curr->key != key)
    {
        return false;
    }
    prev->next = curr->next;
    free(curr);
    return true;
}

void insertAtEnd(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* curr;
    curr = R;
    while(curr->next != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = createNode(key);
    return;
}

void removeAll(unsigned long key)
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct node* curr;
    while(true)
    {
        seek(key);
        curr = seekRecord->curr;
        prev = seekRecord->prev;
        if(curr->key != key)
        {
            return;
        }
        prev->next = curr->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}

void printList()
{
    struct node* curr;
    curr=R->next;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%lu\t",curr->key);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

int main()
{
    seekRecord = (struct seekRecord*) malloc(sizeof(seekRecord));
    createSentinelNode();
    insertAtEnd(11);
    insertAtEnd(22);
    insertAtEnd(33);
    insertAtEnd(11);
    insertAtEnd(44);
    printList();
    removeAll(11);
    printList();
}
```